# Как сохранить координаты элемента в cookie, используя draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, очень нужна помощь. Изложу суть проблемы, Я бы хотел узнать, можно ли вытаскивать координаты элемента передвигающегося при помощи метода draggable, а после эти координаты вставлять в cookie и при обновлении страницы использовать cookie, вставляя координаты в style, что бы при обновлении страницы не терять положение элемента?

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

На всякий случай ссылка на JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kbQPW/61/

```css
#container_move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #6f7294;
  display: block;
}

#screen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 9001;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="container_move">
  <img class="bv" id="screen" src="http://www.v3wall.com/wallpaper/1920_1200/1008/1920_1200_20100813012646423759.jpg">
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(init);

  function init() {
    $("#container_move").draggable({
      handle: 'img'
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы для этого использовал localStorage, пример реализации ниже, сниппет ругается на "SecurityError", но хранение подобного типа данных в LS не несет в себе ничего плохого, собственно примерно для такого его и создали

```css
#container_move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #6f7294;
  display: block;
}

#screen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 9001;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div id="container_move">
  <img class="bv" id="screen" src="http://www.v3wall.com/wallpaper/1920_1200/1008/1920_1200_20100813012646423759.jpg">
</div>

<style>
 #container_move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #6f7294;
  display: block;
}

#screen {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 9001;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
}
</style>

<script>
  $(document).ready(init);

  function init() {
 console.log('init!');
 if(localStorage['container_move']){
  console.log('isset container_move');
  data = JSON.parse(localStorage['container_move']);
  position = {};
  position.top  = data.top  || 0;
  position.left = data.left || 0;
  $("#container_move").css({top:position.top, left:position.left})
   }
    
    $("#container_move").draggable({
       handle: 'img',
        drag: function() {
          localStorage['container_move'] = JSON.stringify({
            'top'  : $(this).offset().top,
            'left' : $(this).offset().left,
          });
      },
    },
   );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Всё супер! Работает прекрасно, только сафари отказывается работать с draggable. Как это проблему можно решить?

Comment: Если работает можете принять ответ как верный. Подскажите пожалуйста, что выводит консоль? @NikitaN